# Dojo slider problem - how to add numbers with slider

Tags: dojo

I have Dojo slider and I need to put  from 0 to 24 h (0,1,2, ... 24).How to achive this ?
I have this:

```
<div id="vertical_monday" style="float: left;"></div>
```

and create like this :

```
var vertical_monday = dojo.byId("vertical_monday");
                var rulesNodeMonday = document.createElement('div');
                vertical_monday.appendChild(rulesNodeMonday);

                var sliderRulesMonday = new dijit.form.VerticalRule({
                    count: 24,
                    style: "width:5px;" 
                },
                rulesNodeMonday);
                var slider = new dijit.form.VerticalSlider({
                    name: "vertical_monday",
                    value: 0,
                    minimum: 1440,
                    maximum: 0,
                    pageIncrement:100,
                    showButtons:true,
                    slideDuration:289,
                    discreteValues: 289,
                    intermediateChanges:true,
                    style: "height:500px;",
                    onChange: function(value) {
                        //dojo.byId("sliderValueMonday").value = value;
                        set_time_labels('mon',used_length['mon'],value);

                        val['mon']=value;
                        var a=(500*(value-used_length['mon']))/1440;



                        var temp_id='mon_'+temp_daily_plan['mon'];
                        $('#'+temp_id).css('height',a);
                    }
                },
                vertical_monday);
```

but it doesn't have numbers . How to add numbers ?

Comment: What does set_time_labels do? I can't see it. Also it looks like you commented out a line to set the value in an INPUT box. Did that work? In your HTML, where's the object you want to have the values displayed in? Run it with Firebug in Firefox, do you get any JS errors?

Comment: @Spacedman I have set count to 24 and I see 24 - , but I want to have -1h -2h .... -24h.

Comment: Doesn't really answer my questions. You have an onChange function that does all sorts of things that don't relate to anything in your HTML. And calls a function, "set_time_labels" that I can't see the definition of. What do these things do? Start from scratch and make a MINIMAL example that either works or fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick and dirty way to do it, not sure if it's the recommended one.

Add a container for the labels, just like you did with the ruler.

```
var labelsNodeMonday = document.createElement("div");
vertical_monday.appendChild(labelsNodeMonday);
```

Then create a `dijit.form.VerticalRuleLabels` instance and place it in that node, explicitly providing the labels as an array:

```
var labelsMonday = new dijit.form.VerticalRuleLabels({
    labels: ["1h", "2h", "3h", "4h"] //.. and so on
}, labelsNodeMonday);
```

Or alternatively, if you don't like to repeat yourself.

```
var labelsMonday = new dijit.form.VerticalRuleLabels({
    getLabels: function() {
        for(var labels = [], i = 1; i <=24; i++) labels.push(i+"h");
        return labels;
    },
}, labelsNodeMonday);
```

Again, I don't know if this is the kosher way. Ideally, there should be something along the lines of:

```
var labelsMonday = new dijit.form.VerticalRuleLabels({
    minimum: 1, maximum: 24, step: 1,
    formatLabel: function(value) { return value + "h"; }
}, labelsNodeMonday);
```

.. but afaik there isn't at the moment.